# How to add new branch to existing GitHub repository as major branch?

Tags: git, github

I have created `GitHub` repository for my project a month ago, and I pushed all my previous implementation on my `github` repo. However, now I came up with a new implementation which is more stable that previous version, updated solution is more efficient. My goal is, I want to keep my previous implementation on my project repository, meanwhile, I intend to introduce new branch on my github repo marked as `major` branch, while mark previous implementation as `default`. How can I make this happen in a secure way? I don't want to lose my previous work, and I want to make sure newly introduced branch can be active as `major` branch, while deactivate `default` branch which holds previous work. How can I do that? Can anyone instruct me how to do with detail workflow? Thanks in advance :)

**Edit**:

To clarify one point, I did not push my new implementation to `github` repo. I want to reopen branch new branch that holds my new implementation, and this new branch will forward to online package building server. Any further assistance please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to lose my previous work, and I want to make sure newly introduced branch can be active as major branch

You can follow [semantic versioning](https://www.sitepoint.com/semantic-versioning-why-you-should-using/) in your project implementation. Just give a *tag* (say, `v1.0.0`) on your *latest commit* of your previous implementation. Then *merge* your updated/latest changes with the default branch master.

Now in future if you want to back/get your previous version then checkout to the tag `v1.0.0`.

1. *Add*, *Commit* your latest changes to a branch (say, `feature`). So, your `feature` branch holds all the latest changes.

   ```
   $ git checkout -b feature
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m 'new implementation'
   $ git push origin HEAD                 # push to remote 'feature' branch
   ```
2. Now *checkout* to `master` branch and give a *tag* on the top of your previous implementation's commit.

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "my previous implementation"
   $ git push --tags                   # push v1.0.0 tag to remote

   $ git checkout -b prev-impl-v1.0.0  # create a new branch ('prev-impl-v1.0.0') from the tag 'v1.0.0' which holds your previous implementation
   $ git push origin HEAD              # push 'prev-impl-v1.0.0' branch
   ```
3. Now merge your updated changes (exists in `feature` branch) into default branch `master`. Merge `feature` branch into `master` branch. If you finished with your updated implementation then give a `new tag` on the top of new implementation's commit.

   ```
   $ git checkout master             # checkout master branch
   $ git pull origin feature         # merge feature with master

   $ git tag -a v2.0.0               # give a new tag ('v2.0.0') on the new implementation

   $ git push origin HEAD            # update the remote 'master'
   $ git push --tags                 # push 'v2.0.0' tag to remote

   $ git checkout -b new-impl-v2.0.0 # create a new branch from tag 'v2.0.0' tag
   $ git push origin HEAD            # push 'new-impl-v2.0.0' branch
   ```

Now your `master` is updated with your latest changes. Also you have different branches like:

**master**           = **new-impl-v2.0.0** = holds new impl. (v2.0.0 tag)
**prev-impl-v1.0.0** = holds previous impl. (v1.0.0 tag)

Now you can create a new branch (say, `feature2`) from your `master` and work on that branch for your next implementation (if necessary)

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b `feature2`

# do changes for your next implementation
```

When you would finish with your next implementation **repeat the #3** as you did for `feature` branch.

If you want to back your previous implementation just `checkout to the specific tag` you want. You have also two branches (`prev-impl-v1.0.0` & `new-impl-v2.0.0`) in which you can checkout to see previous any implementation.

```
 $ git checkout v1.0.0           # checkout to v1.0.0 = previous implementation
 $ git checkout v2.0.0           # checkout to v2.0.0 = new implementation 

 # create a new branch from any checked out tag/commit
 $ git checkout -b <branch-name> # create & checkout a new branch from the tag
```

[More about Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)

Comment: Could you make your answer more detail with git command? My goal is to reopen new branch where all my new implementation will be placed. Your answer is too abstract here.

Comment: Clarify please, - Is your default branch `master` holds previous implementation or updated impl.? - your goal is to backup your previous impl to any other branch and update your default branch `master` with latest changes ?

Comment: my default branch `master` holds the previous implementation. I have not pushed the new implementation to `github` repo yet. I want to make sure I follow right approach. As you know, `git` sometimes complains a lot for this sort of things. Hope you understand :)

Comment: @datageek I tried to give step by step procedure with git commands here showing how people normally manage project versioning. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I am thankful for your help, it is well motivated. I am gonna try your solution on my sites. I'll report question if there is any :)